# PHP array - Foreach, dynamic value - Strange

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I try to generate a dynamic list of values in a PHP associative array and I can't do it.

1) With this code

```
foreach ($states as $state) {
  $state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->ID()] = $state->name();
}
```

I obtain

```
<optgroup label="France">
<option value="01 - Ain">01 - Ain</option>
<option value="02 - Aisne">02 - Aisne</option>
</optgroup>
```

*I obtain the name in value instead of the ID.*

2) With this code

```
foreach ($states as $state) {
  $state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->name()] = $state->ID();
}
```

I obtain

```
<optgroup label="France">
<option value="01 - Ain">77</option>
<option value="02 - Aisne">78</option>
<option value="03 - Allier">79</option>
</optgroup>
```

*I can obtain the ID.*

**My aim is to obtain**

```
<optgroup label="France">
<option value="77">01 - Ain</option>
<option value="78">02 - Aisne</option>
<option value="79">03 - Allier</option>
</optgroup>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

**Edit of 22/10/17 after comments**

My full code

```
add_filter( 'gform_address_types', 'france_address_type' );
function france_address_type( $address_types ) {

$state_options = array('' => array('' => ''));
$states        = EEM_State::instance()->get_all_active_states();
if (! empty($states)) {
    foreach ($states as $state) {
        if ($state instanceof EE_State) {
            $state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->ID()] = $state->name();
        }
    }
}

$address_types[ 'france' ] = array(
    'label'       => 'France',
    'country'     => 'France',
    'zip_label'   => 'Code Postal',
    'state_label' => 'Département',
    'states'      => $state_options
);

return $address_types;
}
```

Comment: Now show the code which generates `select` amd `option`s

Comment: Have you tried reversing the values and key in `$state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->name()] = $state->ID()`, so swap `name()` and `ID()`.

Comment: @u_mulder I have written the ful code.

Comment: @NigelRen do you propose " $state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->name()] = $state->ID();" ? Cause its my solution 2 on my post. This code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$state->name()` apparently corresponds with "01 - Ain", and `$state->ID()` corresponds with `77`, use the latter as the key and the former as the value:

```
foreach ($states as $state) {
  $state_options[$state->country()->name()][$state->ID()] = $state->name();
}
```

Comment: This is what I try on my "1) With this code" but I can't get the ID()

Comment: @Jahnichen That is weird. Does `$state->ID()` return the ID after all? Add some logging.

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this, you can get expected result.

```
<optgroup label="France">
   <?php foreach ($states as $state) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $state->ID(); ?>">
       <?php echo $state->name();?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: `optgroup` label is __obviously__ `$state->country()->name()`

Comment: Yes optgroup is generated in the foreach. Furthemore I need to wrap the code in a variable. I just have post the full code.